# Understanding scikit-learn ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence due to data shape

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, keras, error-handling, scikit-learn

in the past two days I’m struggling to figure a way to correctly shape and feed my data to *sklearn.preprocessing* `fit_transform`. My data is being parsed from thousands of quantum chemistry calculations. I have several features and, at the end a 25x25 matrix related to atomic positions. The final pandas dataFrame looks like this:

```
Feature A (int), Feature B (float), Feature C (float), Feature D (float), [Matrix]
```

The matrix, actually, was padded with zeros and flattened, so what the DataFrame has is a **625x1 numpy array**.

The problem is that when I’m trying to split and fit my data to train my `Sequential` model `X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)` is throwing an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-a0e62fa4eda4> in <module>()
----> 1 X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     83 
     84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     86 
     87 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

It looks like I can’t use my data to fit if it contains a numpy array (or even a list) as one of the features. What should I do in this case?

**P.S.:**

If it is useful, here is one line from X_train (we can see that I have a sub-array and this is what is killing me):

```py
print(X_train[0])
array([2,
       array([1.36220678e+03, 1.05000000e+02, 1.05000000e+02, 1.12460036e+01,
       1.12460877e+01, 1.12461039e+01, 1.12460515e+01, 1.12460803e+01,
       1.12460599e+01, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 1.05000000e+02, 5.33587074e+01, 1.36111111e+01,
       6.75949416e+00, 6.75947066e+00, 6.75946638e+00, 1.70097114e+00,
       1.70097442e+00, 1.70097229e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.05000000e+02, 1.36111111e+01,
       5.33587074e+01, 1.70096614e+00, 1.70097517e+00, 1.70097691e+00,
       6.75949013e+00, 6.75946954e+00, 6.75947172e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.12460036e+01,
       6.75949416e+00, 1.70096614e+00, 5.00000000e-01, 6.05278494e-01,
       6.05278867e-01, 2.26938983e-01, 2.12534321e-01, 2.12455393e-01,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       1.12460877e+01, 6.75947066e+00, 1.70097517e+00, 6.05278494e-01,
       5.00000000e-01, 6.05280577e-01, 2.12534792e-01, 2.12456720e-01,
       2.26940528e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 1.12461039e+01, 6.75946638e+00, 1.70097691e+00,
       6.05278867e-01, 6.05280577e-01, 5.00000000e-01, 2.12456349e-01,
       2.26941094e-01, 2.12535342e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.12460515e+01, 1.70097114e+00,
       6.75949013e+00, 2.26938983e-01, 2.12534792e-01, 2.12456349e-01,
       5.00000000e-01, 6.05279075e-01, 6.05278949e-01, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.12460803e+01,
       1.70097442e+00, 6.75946954e+00, 2.12534321e-01, 2.12456720e-01,
       2.26941094e-01, 6.05279075e-01, 5.00000000e-01, 6.05280203e-01,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       1.12460599e+01, 1.70097229e+00, 6.75947172e+00, 2.12455393e-01,
       2.26940528e-01, 2.12535342e-01, 6.05278949e-01, 6.05280203e-01,
       5.00000000e-01, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
       0.00000000e+00]),
       0.004850999999999999, 0.24708899999999998, 0.28475300000000003,
       0.285264, -0.00352, -0.00028, -0.00072], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's construct a dataframe that can reproduce the `ValueError`

```
import pandas as pd

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'prop_float_%i' % ind: np.random.rand(100) for ind in range(3)})
test_df['prop_int'] = np.random.randint(0,100,100)

# create the matrix column 
test_df['matrix'] = np.random.rand(100).astype('object')
for ind in range(100):test_df.at[ind,'matrix'] = np.random.rand(625)
```

the first five rows of `test_df` looks like

```
    prop_float_0  prop_float_1  prop_float_2  prop_int                                             matrix
0       0.748796      0.413757      0.750549        87  [0.0013304191112200048, 0.8335838936187671, 0....
1       0.982136      0.014367      0.072711        62  [0.13101366609934562, 0.3455947047272854, 0.67...
2       0.767685      0.289047      0.376070        67  [0.5403591994226811, 0.20985464836499557, 0.47...
3       0.894771      0.008032      0.458049        11  [0.5520592944741991, 0.1013914150023918, 0.522...
4       0.174076      0.493082      0.045521        10  [0.3383177346302546, 0.8874405729210008, 0.169...
5       0.701766      0.232873      0.905511        11  [0.42878413331053633, 0.4555373221498983, 0.19...
```

in which the entries in the `matrix` column are `(625,)` arrays.

I assume you want to normalize the `features` together with the `matrix` (**which are atomic positions !!! The atomic positions have different units compared to properties like ground state energies!!!**), then you need to expand the column `matrix` before apply `fit_transform`

```
df_mat = pd.DataFrame(test_df['matrix'].values.tolist()).astype('float')
test_df = test_df.drop('matrix',axis=1)
test_df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
df_mat.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)

flattened_df = pd.concat([test_df,df_mat],axis=1)
```

as you can see, in `flattened_df`, the original `matrix` column is expanded to 625 columns, upon `flattened_df`, you can apply

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

mm_scalar = MinMaxScaler()
transformed_array = mm_scalar.fit_transform(flattened_df)
```

Comment: Dear @meTchaikovsky, Thank you so much! I was almost losing hope. Your explanation was clear and right to the point.

Comment: @HenriqueJunior You're welcome :) I'm really glad I helped :)